# Test fail with NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/AutoCloseableKt

Tags: gradle, kotlin, corda

Recently my tests start fail with a bizarre `NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/AutoCloseableKt`. This class contains 2 inline utility methods and is a part of the `kotlin-stdlib-jre7` compatibility package. I work with JVM 1.8. Further more, the project does not work with `AutoClosable`.

What can be the reason for this?

I use the Corda framework, also I recently added a dependency on Koin if that helps

### The exception:

```
kotlin/AutoCloseableKt
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/AutoCloseableKt
    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.CordappLoader$Companion$createDevCordappJar$1.apply(CordappLoader.kt:150)
    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.CordappLoader$Companion$createDevCordappJar$1.apply(CordappLoader.kt:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.CordappLoader$Companion.createDevCordappJar(CordappLoader.kt:143)
    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.CordappLoader$Companion.access$createDevCordappJar(CordappLoader.kt:59)
    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.CordappLoader$Companion$getPackageURLs$1.invoke(CordappLoader.kt:135)
    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.CordappLoader$Companion$getPackageURLs$1.invoke(CordappLoader.kt:59)
    at kotlin.sequences.TransformingSequence$iterator$1.next(Sequences.kt:174)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toCollection(_Sequences.kt:691)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toMutableList(_Sequences.kt:721)
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.toList(_Sequences.kt:712)
    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.CordappLoader$Companion.getPackageURLs(CordappLoader.kt:138)
    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.CordappLoader$Companion.createDefaultWithTestPackages(CordappLoader.kt:100)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InProcessNode.<init>(NodeBasedTest.kt:134)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$Companion$startInProcessNode$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:805)
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$Companion$startInProcessNode$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:767)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:107)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:119)
    at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.AutoCloseableKt
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 more
```

#### My `./gradle dependencies`

https://scans.gradle.com/s/bta3ize65pnc4/dependencies?toggled=W1sxXSxbMSwyMDhdXQ

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by version skew. Can you try recompiling the CorDapp with the following dependency?

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: Our kotlin version is '1.3.10',  so kotlin-stdlib-jre8 for it does not exist (it was depricated and replaced with kotlin-stdlib-jdk8)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by bumping? What to what?

Comment: Try using `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"` as the new dependency.

Comment: Adding `..kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.10` had no effect. I believe the `AutoCloseable` class in question is not present there since it is supposed to come from JDK8